# Phonegap GeoLocation - Frequency Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an application whereby I need to allow the user to change the frequency of the position update him/herself rather than hard coding it.

Below is something that I have tried, however am getting a Timeout error for some reason.  Did anyone ever encounter such a similar scenario?  Or maybe I have something wrong in my code below?

```
watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(win, fail, { maximumAge: 10000, timeout: (parseFloat(userfreq)*1000), enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

userfreq is a value that is loaded from the database and is a value in seconds, such as 0.25seconds.  Therefore I am multiplying it by 1000 to change it to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `Timeout expired` Position error, either watchPosition is called multiple times (with same variable) or watchPosition is called multiple times at some other place with another variable.

Check the first two screenshots, watchPosition throws error if it is called for two times either with same variable or different variable.
[image]

[image]

To solve this problem, use `clearWatch` with that variable.

Below screenshot shows geolocation result after `clearWatch`
[image]

Comment: I have tried this, and am even clearing the watch before I actually set watchID = navigator.geolocation....  however this did not the trick.  Also the ID is unique and once I'm ready from the event listener I am clearing it.

Comment: @user1809790 I got this from [W3](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html), search for `error.TIMEOUT` in that page.

`error.TIMEOUT` will come, if **No fresh enough cached position available.** or **No cached position available at all.**